# вектор векторов для работы с двумерным массивом. вопрос

Tags: c++, матрицы, vector, контейнеры

В видеоуроке по алгоритмам и структурам данных на ютубе увидел пример использования вектора (версия1), хотя раньше приходилось использовать другой пример из интернета (версия2). Есть ли между ними какая-либо разница, надо ли во втором случае использовать reserve(m*n)?

---1 версия---

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>>K;
K.resize(n + 1);
for (int i=0; i<=n;i++){
K[i].resize(m + 1); }
```

---2 версия---

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>mass(m, std::vector<int> (n));
```

Comment: Во втором случае вы посылаете количество элементов в векторе в конструктор, и это работает быстрее. Никогда не используйте в цикле for тип int когда перебираете массив, только size_t  и инкремент ++i будет работать гораздо быстрее, чем i++.

Comment: @zurn Ну, еще с `size_t` могу согласиться - и то иногда *удобнее* `int`, но что для простого целочисленного типа `++i` отличается от `i++`, и не просто отличается, а *гораздо быстрее*... При современных-то компиляторах/оптимизаторах...

Comment: спс за реакцию, только недавно начал обращаться к книге Страуструпа, но не видел, чтобы в примерах  по перебору массива использовался size_t. где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: @zurn Просто именно этот тип возвращает `size()` у `vector`а, да и у других контейнеров, поэтому, вообще говоря, лучше использовать именно этот тип. Теоретически возможна ситуация, когда `int` просто не хватит для индексации. Но вообще использовать индексы при обходе контейнера - годится только для тех, у кого реально быстрая операция индекса, где данные хранятся последовательно в массиве - вектор, `array`, строка. С натяжкой - дек. Поэтому в общем случае перебор элементов контейнера лучше выполнять с помощью итераторов, а не индексов.

Comment: @Harry а итераторы разве не медленнее перебора по индексам? Если погуглить, то сравнения циклов говорит о том, что итераторы медленнее. Или это не так?

Comment: @zurn https://ideone.com/7hxhrP - как видите, даже для вектора это не совсем так...

Answer (score 1):

У вас вообще-то разный результат получается...

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>>K;
K.resize(n + 1);
for (int i=0; i<=n;i++){
    K[i].resize(m + 1); 
}
```

создает матрицу `(n+1)x(m+1)`, в то время как второй вариант -

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>mass(m, std::vector<int> (n));
```

создает матрицу `mxn`. (О разных типах элементов говорить не буду :))

Как тут уже писали в комментариях, второй код и короче, и в общем случае быстрее. Никакой `reserve()` при этом использовать не надо - когда вы в конструкторе указываете размер, необходимая память выделяется сразу. Согласитесь, даже смешно говорить "выдели-ка мне N памяти, а потом зарезервируй мне ее".

И еще - несколько раз встречал странную ошибку - создав такую матрицу, люди вдруг начинали вносить в нее данные с помощью `push_back()` (и подумал, не с этими ли планами связан ваш вопрос о `reserve`). Нет, это уже ошибка - все элементы *уже* созданы и *инициализированы нулевым значением*.

Comment: (n+1)x(m+1) преподаватель выделял для визуального оформления, чтобы с нулевым столбцом и нулевой строкой далее не работать. теперь увидел, что mass.capacity() и mass[0].capacity() соответствуют m и n сразу.